# Add item on dict at specific depth

Tags: python, list, dictionary, elasticsearch, recursion

I'm working with Elasticsearch and I need to build a dict object, JSON-like, to query a complex aggrupation.

Each aggrupation has this format:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "agg_by_field_1": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "source": "whatever"
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

But each aggregation also has a leaf with the next aggregation:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "agg_by_field_1": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "source": "whatever"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "agg_by_field_2": {
                "terms": {
                    "script": {
                        "source": "whatever_2"
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Now I have a plain `list` with each of the aggregations:

```
[
    {
        "agg_by_field_1": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "whatever"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "agg_by_field_2": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "whatever_2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
]
```

So, how can I achieve this data structure, second piece of code, in python? Put in a dict a new leaf for each aggregation item.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Python supports such structures out of the box. This is called a nested `Dictionary`. You can read more about this here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/nested-dictionary

As a matter of fact, your code will just work without changing a thing:

```py
>>> d = {
... "aggs": {
...     "agg_by_field_1": {
...         "terms": {
...             "script": {
...                 "source": "whatever"
...             }
...         },
...         "aggs": {
...             "agg_by_field_2": {
...                 "terms": {
...                     "script": {
...                         "source": "whatever_2"
...                         }
...                     }
...                  }
...             }
...          }
...     }
... }
>>> d
{'aggs': {'agg_by_field_1': {'terms': {'script': {'source': 'whatever'}}, 'aggs': {'agg_by_field_2': {'terms': {'script': {'source': 'whatever_2'}}}}}}}
```

```py
>>> d = [
    {
        "agg_by_field_1": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "whatever"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "agg_by_field_2": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "source": "whatever_2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
]
>>> d
[{'agg_by_field_1': {'terms': {'script': {'source': 'whatever'}}}}, {'agg_by_field_2': {'terms': {'script': {'source': 'whatever_2'}}}}]
```